# checking if ArrayList is sorted

Tags: c#, sorting, listbox

I'm wondering if it is possible to do and if I could loop to check if a ArrayList is sorted, and if it's not, show a message box?

This is what I've tried :

```
if (!aList.Sort)
{
   MessageBox.Show("The list isn't sorted");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[`Sort()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.sort.aspx) is a method. I think you want the [`Sorted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.sorted.aspx) property.

```
if (!aList.Sorted)
```

Note that it's possible for items to be "in ascending order" without the listbox itself enforcing the sort order. If you want to just check whether all the items as displayed *are* in ascending order, that's a different matter.

EDIT: To check whether a sequence (whether that's the items in a listbox or elements in an `ArrayList`, which may turn out to be what you're actually interested in) are sorted, you merely need to iterate over them, and compare each item with the previous one. This is easier done with a generic collection, but...

```
public static bool IsSorted(IEnumerable sequence)
{
    // Now assuming that list
    using (IEnumerator iterator = sequence.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            // An empty sequence is always sorted
            return true;
        }
        IComparable previous = (IComparable) iterator.Current;
        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            IComparable next = (IComparable) iterator.Current;
            if (next.CompareTo(previous) < 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            previous = next;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Error 1 'System.Collections.ArrayList' does not contain a definition for 'Sorted' and no extension method 'Sorted' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @KevinChun: You said a listbox, not an `ArrayList`. If you're asking about `ArrayList`, that's entirely different. Please be careful to be accurate when you're asking questions.

Comment: @KevinChun: I've edited my answer to show how you would check for a general sequence being sorted.